# Display data to Debug Console (uwp with woocommerce)

Tags: c#, wordpress, visual-studio, uwp

I have this code for searching  order products

```
 var p = await wc.GetProducts(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
              { "orderby", "id" }, { "filter[search]", "1884" }
               });
```

I using this plugin  for woocommerce

```
https://github.com/XiaoFaye/WooCommerce.NET
```

I need to display data from `p`  , how I can do this?